# How to get json objects from Controller in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm writing mail validation controller with jquery ajax and php.

After I validate message in php controller i'm trying to get it by ajax and print on the screen by jquery.

My ajax code looks like that

....

```
success: function(data) {
     var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (jsonObj.result) {
                //succes message

        }
        else {
            $.each([jsonObj.errors],function(key,value){
                console.log(jsonObj.errors);
            });

        }
    }
```

console.log of error shows:

```
[Object]
0: Object
email: "Email validation error message"
name: "Name validation error message"
phone: "phone validation error message"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

.......

how to get value of email message to print it on screen ? 
I want to do something like : 
If email message error is not empty show error message.

Comment: from the controller return the data as JSON, ex: return data as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to below:

```
success: function(data) {
     var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if (jsonObj.result) {
            //succes message

    }
    else {
        $.each([jsonObj.errors],function(key,value){
            if (typeof jsonObj.errors[0].email !== 'undefined') {
                console.log(jsonObj.errors[0].email);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an array in controller:

```
  Array
    (
        [message] => json object from controller
        [data] => Array
            (
                [name] => user25354i
                [profile_views] => 234
            )

    )
$array = array('message'=>"json object from controller",
               'data'=>array('name'=>'user25354i','profile_views'=>'234'));
```

return $array as: `echo json_encode($array);exit;`

Now in jQuery it will be treated as json object by default, so you can simply access this array as shown below:

```
success: function(response) {
     alert(response.message);
     alert(response.data.name);
     so on...
    }
```

Hope it will answer your question!